# Applying formula to multiple columns with a set row number

Tags: excel, vba

I have a formula to apply to columns I to Z, commencing in row 3 until the last row of data in column C.

I managed to define `lastRow`, but I cannot work out how to apply the formula to columns I to Z.

```vb
Sub Calculation()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet 2")

With ws1
    lastRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("I3:I" & lastRow).Formula = "=1+2"
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the formula you want to use, is it relative or static?

Comment: `.Range("I3:Z" & lastRow).Formula = "=1+2"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small change in the Range

```vb
    Sub Calculation()

        Dim ws1 As Worksheet
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim lastRow As Long
        Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet 2")

        With ws1
            lastRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            .Range("Z3:I" & lastRow).Formula = "=1+2"
            
        End With
    End Sub
```

Let's try and understand how Range works in VBA
The VBA Range Object represents a cell or multiple cells in your Excel worksheet.

1. A single cell : **Range("A1")**
2. A row : **Range("1:1")**
3. A column : **Range("A: A")**
4. For Contiguous Cells : **Range("A1:C5")**
5. For Non-Contiguous Cells : **Range("A1:C5, F1:F5")**
6. For Intersection of two ranges : **Range("A1:C5 F1:F5")**
   (For intersection cell, remember there is no comma operator)